# Xcode table view reload continually adds data to the table

Tags: xcode, uitableview, removeall

I have an rss parser as part of my app code, and it is working fine and loading the rss xml file and populating the tableview fine.

The problem is with a refresh/reload button, which does reload the rss data, but it APPENDS the new data to the table and the table just grows and grows in size.

What the behaviour should do is to clear the old table data and rebuild the table with the new data - so that the table always shows just ONE set of data and doesn't keep growing every time the reload/refresh is pressed.

The table build code is as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
cell.textLabel.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"date"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"title"];

[cell.textLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[cell.textLabel sizeToFit];

[cell.detailTextLabel setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
[cell.detailTextLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
[cell.detailTextLabel sizeToFit];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
return cell;
}
```

And the reload/refresh button code is:

```
- (void)reloadRss {
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20)];
UIBarButtonItem * barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:activityIndicator];
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:barButton];
[barButton release];
[activityIndicator release];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[self performSelector:@selector(parseXMLFileAtURL) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
[newsTable reloadData];
}
```

I have tried to solve this by adding the line:

```
if (stories) { [stories removeAllObjects]; }
```

to the reload section, which I think should work and does clear the table, but the app then crashes the app with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Any ideas or suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, have now solved this!

Was due to "autoreleasing" elements of the array, so after clearing this out, they were invalid.

Removing `autorelease` and just releasing these objects in the final dealloc worked.

Answer (score 0):

The Code **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** does mean, that you want connect at a variable that does not exists anymore.

In your code example, I can see, the problem to see at the following two lines of code:

```
[activityIndicator release];
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

You release the activityIdicator befor starting the Animating.

Try to release at the end of the function.

```
[activityIndicator startAnimating];
[self performSelector:@selector(parseXMLFileAtURL) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
[newsTable reloadData];
[activityIndicator release];
```

Comment: Agreed, but this isn't the problem. The code snippet shown above does work, even with the bad ordering. It is only when I add the line [stories removeAllObjects] that the BAD_ACCESS happens. With this one line it crashes, without that one line it works fine but doesn't clear the table before reloading.